# How to use the telerik window to open a page with a constant panel at the bottom?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radwindow

I have the following case :

I use [RadWindow](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) , to open a specific page (which) exist in my solution.

Now i want to put a panel with set of buttons in the bottom of this window (constant panel) seperate from the page.

but i don't know how to do this.

---

```
 <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" EnableShadow="true">
        <Windows>
            <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server" ShowContentDuringLoad="false" Width="400px"
                Height="400px" Title="Telerik RadWindow" Behaviors="Default" EnableShadow="true" KeepInScreenBounds="true" Modal="true" VisibleStatusbar="true">
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>

            </telerik:RadWindow>

        </Windows>
    </telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

---

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        function openRadWin() {
            radopen("About.aspx", "RadWindow1");
        }

        function openPopUp() {
            window.open("About.aspx", "WindowPopup", "width=400px, height=400px, resizable");
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like the effect in this demo:  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/demoemail/defaultcs.aspx -- The reply and close buttons on the the popup RadWindow are part of the loaded page.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the ContentTemplate it seems, not an external page. Nevertheless, simple CSS with position: fixed (or absolute + a div wrapper with position: relative) and bottom: 0px for the wrapper of the buttons should get the job done, be it in a RadWindow or directly in the browser. There are many ways to position elements like that.

Other options are using richer controls like RadNotification (see [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/notification/examples/sizeinpercent/defaultcs.aspx)) or RadSplitter to put your static content in its bottom pane (see [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/splitter/examples/resizewithwindow/defaultcs.aspx) and [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/splitter/examples/splitterorientation/defaultcs.aspx)).